# How to select text in input on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code write *"I'm selected input!"* to console, but does not select text in the input

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="foo">
```

**And javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').on('change', function(){
        $(this).select();
    });
    $('#foo').on('select', function(){
        console.log("I'm selected input!");
    });
});
```

**UPD 1:** `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` does bot working
**UPD 2:** This code does not working too:

```
$('#foo').on('change', function(){
    $(this).focusout(function(){
        $(this).select().focus();
    });
});
```

**UPD 3:** When I use `debugger` I see selected text

*P.S. sorry for my bad English :)*

Comment: `console.log("I'm selected input!");` change to `console.log(this.value);`

Comment: A side question: Are you sure that onChange() is a valid event for an ordinary input field?

Comment: the text does not stand out, what difference what I would log?

Comment: I need to select text if it would not valid. What event i can use?

Comment: Try `$(this).focus().select();` I believe focus is clearing out selection.

Comment: in Chrome, the code both outputs the correct thing into the console and selects the text in the input (http://jsfiddle.net/bjB6j/)... what browser are you testing it in?

Comment: Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m, and I don't see the selection

Comment: `$(this).focus().select();` same effect

Comment: same Chrome, I see the selection... but no other browser, strange... very strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many events running there at the same time! So you need to delay the select method. In addition, $(this) is different within the setInterval/setTimeout method so you need to cache it as follows:

```
 $(function() {

    $('#foo').change(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.select();
        },10);
    });
    $('#foo').select(function(){
        alert("I'm selected input!");
    });
});
```

Tested with many  browsers

Comment: with pleasure @Vladowski !